# How do I move my android device's screen using adb?

Tags: android, resize, adb, screen, resolution

I am customizing the screen and resolution of my phone since there are some broken spots on it. I changed to a rather small resolution so I'm getting these black bars at top and bottom. Is there a way for me to move the screen up or down leaving just a border on either top or bottom? Thanks.

Tried `adb shell wm overscan <a,b,c,d>` to no avail.